# Output dynamic results as csv from swi-Prolog

Tags: csv, prolog

I built a model in Prolog, which generates dynamic results when I do requiring through compiler. I wanna output the dynamic results as csv from swi-prolog. But because it's dynamic and each moment the columns and rows numbers are changing.

My question is is there anyway I can rewrite the output csv file (cover the old one)? Otherwise how can I output the results when columns and rows are keep changing?

Comment: Isn't it just setting the correct mode (`write`) in your `open/3` or `open/4` call?

Comment: Is this question specific to SWI?

Comment: @false.... it appears to be: *I wanna output the dynamic results as csv from swi-prolog*

Comment: @lurker: I do not see anything specific to SWI that's not also of relevance to any other Prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lurker said I think you just want to make sure the output mode of `open/3` is set to `write`.  I have the following which I think does what want you want. You can adapt the header row and the first column to have special properties if you desire. Adapted from([DCG for file output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294900/dcg-for-file-output)).

```
csvfile(Headers,Rows) -->
    headerrow(Headers),
    normalrows(Rows).

headerrow([]) --> [newline].
headerrow([X]) -->atom(X),[newline].
headerrow([X,Y|Rest]) --> atom(X),atom(', '), headerrow([Y|Rest]).

normalrows([])-->[newline].
normalrows([X|Rest]) --> row(X),normalrows(Rest).

row([H|Rest]) -->
    firstitem(H),
    restitems(Rest).

firstitem(H)--> atom(H),atom(', ').

restitems([]) --> [newline].
restitems([X]) -->atom(X),[newline].
restitems([X,Y|Rest]) --> atom(X),atom(', '), restitems([Y|Rest]).

atom(A) -->[atom(A)].

output(Stream,newline) :-nl(Stream).
output(Stream,atom(A)):- format(Stream,"~w",[A]).

csvfile_header_rows(File,Header,Rows):-
    phrase(csvfile(Header,Rows),Ts),
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open(File,write,Stream),
        maplist(output(Stream),Ts),
        close(Stream)


    ).
```

Example:

```
?-csvfile_header_rows('csv_test.csv',[name,age,sex],[[bob,20,m],[wilma,23,f],[bert,34,m]]).
```